# Is it possible to set machine dual boot with MAC OS?

Tags: mac, windows-7, ubuntu, operating-systems

I have an ACER E732Z machine i want to install secondary OS as MAC is it possible ?if possible which version of MAC is adopted?

Comment: Might be worth nothing that it's illegal to instal Mac OS on anything else than a Mac.

Comment: To put a finer point on what @Kevin said, Stack Exchange sites such as StackOverflow and SuperUser are not the places to ask for help violating your license agreements.

Answer (score 0):

While technically possible (although a bit of bios hacking would be nessecary) as Kevin said correctly this would be a violation on the Mac OSX EULA and is frowned upon on SU. For this reason many questions tagged "[hackintosh](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hackintosh)" are closed here.